Power BI Rankx issue
I'm trying to create, what I thought was a relatively easy measure to rank sales (amount) per store.
But I'm having an issue where stores can have the same rank, despite having huge differences in their sales value, and I'm not quite sure how to proceed.
Table A has a date column, a StoreID which I use to get the Store Name from another Table, Type column which I filter between, and then Amount.
Small sample of data:
There are millions of rows where there are multiple rows per day per store, per type with various Amount.



Date
StoreID
Type
Amount
Country




2024-07-09
ABC1
XY1
100
SWE


2024-07-09
ABC1
XY2
150
SWE


2024-07-09
ABC1
XY3
150
SWE


2024-07-09
ABC2
XY2
100
SWE


2024-07-09
ABC3
XY2
175
SWE


2024-07-09
ABC4
XY4
200
SWE



What I'm trying to create is a measure that ranks the Stores depending on their sum of Amount.
In my report I have 4 table visualizations, one for each country with all their respective Stores, their rank and the sum of the Amount. I also have a date slicer and a slicer for switching between the various Types we have. Single-select only.
However, the ranking like I mentioned gives me weird results where two (or even more) stores can have the same rank even though they have vastly different Amounts.
I've tried many iterations of my measure and even asked ChatGPT for help but didn't lead anywhere. Only variations of the same issue...
Current version that gives me the issue I described:
VAR _Country = SELECTEDVALUE(TableB[Country])
RETURN
 
  RANKX(
    FILTER(
    ALL(TableB),
    TableB[Country] = _Country),
    [Amount (EUR)],,DESC,Dense)

I'm not quite sure what do to here, I've tried expanding with filters and "all" for Type etc but still not quite right results...
Any suggestions?

What are the ranking output you got for above mentioned table?

The issue in your measure is you put ALL. This will concider all the columns in the table to do the ranking. Ranking criteria should be column level rather than table level.
VAR _Country =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( TableB[Country] )
RETURN
    RANKX (
        FILTER ( ALL ( TableB[Amount] ), TableB[Country] = _Country ),
        [Amount (EUR)],
        DESC,
        DENSE
    )

If you want a more dynamic ranking replace ALL with ALLSELECTED as below.
VAR _Country =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( TableB[Country] )
RETURN
    RANKX (
        FILTER ( ALLSELECTED ( TableB[Amount] ), TableB[Country] = _Country ),
        [Amount (EUR)],
        DESC,
        DENSE
    )


thanks for the reply. I can't really get that working, It's not letting me input "TableB[Country] = _Country" I can't get that column there. It only lets me input the Amount column again?

What is the error your are getting?

"Unexpected value for ORDER argument in RANKX function. Use 0/FALSE/DESC for descending order or 1/TRUE/ASC for ascending order."
So I'm guessing FILTER part is not including "TableB[Country] = _Country)" properly?

Can I ask why do you require this country filter?

Sorry for late reply, went on holiday. The issue was due a to an "apparently" known bug where if you sort by the ranking column in the table if doesn't work... so I just had to stop sorting
